# Conditional Statement Only Checking One of My Elements jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code that is basically a conditional statement that checks multiple conditions.

As you can see it checks the elements with a class of `.input-bravo` to see if it has a value and to see if it has a class of `is-valid`.

```
$('#step-1-btn').click(function() {
  if($('.form-step-1 .input--bravo').val() && $('.form-step-1 .input--bravo').hasClass('is-valid') ) {
    alert('This worked')
  }
  else {
    alert('This did not work');
  }
});
```

The issue I am having with this is that it only checks one of the elements with `.input-bravo` and then will pass even known other elements with that class don't shouldn't pass. How do I check all of these elements on my page instead of one?

Thanks, Nick

Comment: Iterate over each element: `$('.form-step-1 .input--bravo').each(function() {....});`

Comment: You need a loop of some kind. How could it use the result of all in a single operation?

Comment: @cale_b why not write this as an actual answer?

Comment: @Soviut - no time, I'm happy to let someone else write a robust answer - and would be happy to upvote it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To check if all the elements have that class, and a value

```
var elems = $('.form-step-1 .input--bravo');

var filtered = elems.filter(function() {
    return $(this).hasClass('is-valid') && this.value !== "";
});

if ( elems.length === filtered.length ) {...
```

Comment: that `.filter()` made me to start reading some doc. Looks cool :D

Comment: Quick question: why the use of `this.value` as opposed to `$(this).val()`?  Is there that significant of a performance improvement?  I like to performance-optimize, but also like to consider consistency in code, so am trying to learn from an expert like yourself!

Comment: @cale_b - wrapping `this` in jQuery won't be noticable performance wise, neither will calling `val()` as opppose to just getting the `value` property, so it doesn't really matter. But, as it takes about the same time and amount of characters to write both, I like to use `this.value` just because it saves two function calls and is just as easy to read.